# Celery not discovering tasks inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, celery

I have a very simple implementation.

#### `/lib/queue/__init__.py`

```
from celery import Celery
from os import environ


REDIS_URI = environ.get('REDIS_URI')


app = Celery('tasks',
             broker=f'redis://{REDIS_URI}')
app.autodiscover_tasks([
    'lib.queue.cache',
], force=True)
```

#### `/lib/queue/cache/tasks.py`

```
from lib.queue import app

@app.task
def some_task():
    pass
```

#### `Dockerfile`

```
RUN git clone <my_repo> /usr/src/lib
WORKDIR /usr/src/lib
RUN python3 setup.py install

CMD ["celery", "-A", "worker:app", "worker", "--loglevel=info", "--concurrency=4"]
```

#### `/worker.py`

```
from lib.queue import app
```

This works just fine if I initialize command line without Docker.

```
celery -A worker:app worker --loglevel=info

> [tasks]
> . lib.queue.cache.tasks.some_task
```

However, when I run it inside Docker, the tasks remain blank:

```
> [tasks]
```

## Question:

Any thoughts as to why celery would not be able to find the library and tasks inside Docker? I am using another `Dockerfile` with an almost identical setup to push the tasks, and it is able to access `lib.queue.cache.tasks` no problem.

Comment: Do you have `REDIS_URI` env var set in your container? You may want to add `-e REDIS_URI` to your `docker run` call.

Comment: Thanks @Nebril. I do have it in my `docker-compose.yml`, and I can see that celery is receiving the right value and connecting to Redis. I think the issue is that the `lib` module is not being loaded right. But, I am not sure why.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: hmm... well, it is working now. I don't remember, but I will go back and check. If I don't respond (and you don't have it resolved) by the end of the weekend, ping me again.

Comment: @TheBrewmaster Can you post your solution. Could be helpful for the community.
I am facing a similar issue right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have been asked to provide my solution a couple times, here it is. HOWEVER, it may not really be helpful since what I am doing now is slightly different.

Inside my worker file, where `app` is defined, I have just a single task.

```py
app = Celery("tasks", broker=f"redis://{REDIS_URI}:{REDIS_PORT}/{REDIS_DB}")

@app.task
def run_task(task_name, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"Running {task_name}. Received...")
    print(f"- args: {args}")
    print(f"- kwargs: {kwargs}")
    module_name, method_name = task_name.split(".")
    module = import_module(f".{module_name}", package="common.tasks")
    task = getattr(module, method_name)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    retval = loop.run_until_complete(task(*args, **kwargs))
```

This may not be relevant to most people since it takes a string argument to import a coroutine and execute that. This really is because my tasks are sharing some functions that also need to execute in async world.